# conditional statement in while loop

Tags: c++, conditional-statements

I must have missed something. I'm doing an exercise to learn c++ and it asks that if a user inputs either c,p,t or g character then carry on, otherwise re-request prompt, so I wrote this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(void){
  cout << "Please enter one of the following choices:" << endl;
  cout << "c) carnivore\t\t\tp) pianist\n";
  cout << "t) tree\t\t\t\tg) game\n";
  char ch;
  do{
    cout << "Please enter a c, p, t, or g: ";
    cin >> ch;
    cout << "\"" << ch << "\"" << endl;
  }while(ch != 'c' || ch != 'p' || ch != 't' || ch != 'g');

  cout << "End" << endl;

  cin.clear();
  cin.ignore();
  cin.get();

  return 0;
}
```

This does not work and all I get is the prompt re-requesting it even when pressing either of the correct characters.

However if I change this line:

```
while(ch != 'c' || ch != 'p' || ch != 't' || ch != 'g');
```

to

```
while(ch != 'c' && ch != 'p' && ch != 't' && ch != 'g');
```

why is that? My understanding is that the "OR" statement should work as one of the tests is correct.

Comment: The OR "working" means the loop evaluates to true, causing it to loop again.

Comment: You can condense that loop by just using a while loop as well: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html#faq-15.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> why is that? My understanding is that the "OR" statement should work as one of the tests is correct.

Exactly. There is always *one of the tests* that passes. A character will either be not `'c'`, or not `'p'`. It can't be both `'c'` and `'p'`. So the condition is always true, leading to an infinite loop.

The alternative condition with the conjunctions works because it is false as soon as `ch` is equal to one of the alternatives: one of the inequalities is false, and thus the whole condition is false.

Comment: Just to be pedantic, a character can be not `c` and not `p`. :-) But the gist of your answer is correct (i.e., if the character is `c`, it is by definition `not p`).

Comment: @vanza: R. Martinho Fernandes' description isn't at all in conflict with your clarification.  In English prose 'or' isn't necessarily exclusive; whether or not it's exclusive is generally determined by context.  That's one reason why English would make a poor programming language.

Answer (score 3):

> My understanding is that the "OR" statement should work as one of the tests is correct.

Well, you could use `||`, but the expression would have to be:

```
while(!(ch == 'c' || ch == 'p' || ch == 't' || ch == 'g'));
```

By applying the [De Morgan's law](http://De%20Morgan%27s%20laws), the above simplifies to:

```
while(ch != 'c' && ch != 'p' && ch != 't' && ch != 'g');
```

Comment: That DeMorgan, so caring for the needs of programmers everywhere.